# Is it normal to have the same tables with different prefixes on WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to clean up my site a bit, and delete taxonomies I don't use and entries on tables from plugins I have deleted. While looking at PHP admin I noticed the same tables appear multiple times with different prefixes, why is that? Is that normal?

Pictures of the tables:
[image]
[image]

I looked at my `wp-config.php` file, check that the prefix there is "wp", exported the full database, and then deleted all the other prefixes. The site seemed to be working fine, but as long as I do a back-up or a snapshot, tons of new tables with the same contents (same rows) but different prefixes appear.

Should I delete the duplicates? They take quite a bit of space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Alejandro, you should have only one per website. to determine the correct table you have to check your wp-config.php file there should be a line that contains the prefix. looking at your db its likely that the `fhrmpf_wp_` is the correct one. Your hosting panel may have upgraded your table prefix to make your website more secure

Comment: Yeah, I did that, it was just "wp_" and deleted all the others. But then they showed up again when creating a snapshot or a backup, not sure if it could be the cause.

Comment: I had the same question. Did you ever find out why the kept showing up when you create a snapshot or backup? I'm using Duplicator plugin for backup

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 yes, it was because of the WP Reset Plugin.

Comment: @AlejandroGoffa Thanks for the reply. I didn't realize plugins would do that. I don't have that particular plugin, but for anyone who is having `WP Reset Pro`, this post (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/database-with-repeating-tables-preceded-by-6-letter-prefix-keeps-growing-in-size/) says `Advanced Database Cleaner PRO` was used to fix the issue.